# What verb for taking advantage fits in "I don't want to ________ on the friendship"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

What word am I misplacing that means 'to abuse' but takes the preposition 'on.'
For example,

> My best friend the attorney could give me some free advice here, but I don't want to ____ on the friendship.
>
> My sister's wife is a doctor and could probably solve this, but I don't want to _______ on the relationship. (get free advice at someone else's disadvantage)

Comment: Why can't you use 'My best friend the attorney could give me some free advice here, but I don't want to **abuse our** friendship.'

Comment: @Christopher: this seems like a fill-the-gap type of exercise, so, you can't change the sentence.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It's possible you're looking for *impose on*.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impose)

> (*intransitive verb*) to take unwarranted advantage of something
>   imposed on his good nature

Comment: Do you have any examples of imposing on a friendship or relationship? That doesn’t sound right to me.

Comment: @David: Googling "impose on our friendship" gives you quite a few examples.

Comment: @David It was the first thing I thought of, Peter beat me to it.

Comment: My reply to your comment has been wiped for some strange reason. No matter. The phrase I was thinking of is “ make a convenience of”. But that only really works with people, not with friendship.

Answer (score 22):

Another word in the same vein as the others is *presume*, as in I wouldn’t presume on our friendship...

This construction was [more common historically](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=presume+on+*+friendship%2Cimpose+on+*+friendship&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cpresume%20on%20%2A%20friendship%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpresume%20on%20your%20friendship%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpresume%20on%20the%20friendship%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpresume%20on%20our%20friendship%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpresume%20on%20his%20friendship%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cimpose%20on%20%2A%20friendship%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bimpose%20on%20your%20friendship%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bimpose%20on%20our%20friendship%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cpresume%20on%20*%20friendship%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bpresume%20on%20your%20friendship%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpresume%20on%20the%20friendship%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpresume%20on%20our%20friendship%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpresume%20on%20his%20friendship%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cimpose%20on%20*%20friendship%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bimpose%20on%20your%20friendship%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bimpose%20on%20our%20friendship%3B%2Cc0) than the related phrase "impose on our/a/the friendship", though in recent years they seem to be about equally common.

Comment: I had never heard this sense of this word until today, but according to the definition in MW, this seems closest to what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 13):

**Capitalise on**

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/capitalize):

> Take the chance to gain advantage from.

Answer (score 10):

"Impinge" seems like a fit as well.

Google:
verb
1. have an effect or impact, especially a negative one.

Comment: This would be better with an actual dictionary reference; google isn't an original source.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible you are looking for the word *lean*:

> 2. To incline the weight of the body so as to be supported: leaning against the doorpost.
> 3. To rely for assistance or support: Lean on me for help.

Source: [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lean)

(3) is the literal definition that fits your question. One could argue you are kind of using the word in a metaphorical sense and (2) supports that.

"When we go out for drinks, you usually pick up the tab, but I don't want to lean on our friendship."

Answer (score 6):

Is the single word specifically for that sentence? Or is it just to describe taking advantage of a relationship?

Cause the way I would say it would be: I don't want to [exploit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exploit) the friendship.

Comment: You need a citation for your answer (the best one so far in my opinion) so here you go: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exploit. I hope you don't mind my editing your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for the phrase *to prey on*:

> 2. To exploit, victimize, or take advantage of someone or something.
>   *There are many thieves and con-artists in the city who prey on unsuspecting tourists.
>
>   These megacorporations are all too willing to prey upon consumers.*

(source: [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/prey+on))

but in my experience it's more often used for persons than for relations. That would make your first example

> My best friend the attorney could give me some free advice here, but I don't want to prey on him/her.

Comment: Thank you. That certainly fits the parameters, but that has a very intentional and negative connotation. Can you think of anything that would have a more unintentional but annoying connotation?

Comment: It does, but I went for this because you used 'to abuse' which is also quite negative ...

Answer (score 3):

I would say "I don't want to *trade on* the relationship".

Webster's: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trade

> **trade on**
>   : to take often unscrupulous advantage of : EXPLOIT

Answer (score 2):

1) My best friend the attorney could give me some free advice here, but I don't want to profit from our friendship.

2) My best friend the attorney could give me some free advice here, but I don't want to strain our friendship.

and (but not a single word)

3) My best friend the attorney could give me some free advice here, but I don't want to overtax our friendship.

Comment: Good suggestions, but here on ELU, we like to have citations for suggestions.  Could you please add some references and justify why you think these the most appropriate words?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Infringe could be a good fit.  Merriam-Webster definition:

> to encroach upon in a way that violates law or the rights of another

But Googles second result for definition is more how it is used informally:

> act so as to limit or undermine (something); encroach on.
>
> synonyms: undermine, erode, diminish, weaken, impair, damage, compromise;

Answer (score 0):

You can’t really use this in the specific sentence of the OP, but, for the record, another way of expressing the idea is with the phrase:

**Make a convenience of**

An example of the way I would tend to use it is:

> “I don’t want to appear to be making a convenience of him”

The “appear” has the force of making it clear that I value my relationship with the person.

See [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-a-convenience-of):

> **make a convenience of** [in British]
>
> *to take advantage of; impose upon*

Although I have been informed that this is not American usage, and Collins’ definition states that it is British English, the Google ngram viewer has many examples of American usage, including [one](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BtDz3DX-wrAC&pg=PA485&dq=%22make+a+convenience+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHirDApI7jAhUdSRUIHdf5C68Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22make%20a%20convenience%20of%22&f=false) from Henry James’ *The Portrait of a Lady*:

> ‘She made a convenience of me.’

However the ngrams also shows declining use in both forms of English since about 1960. (A clue to the era in which my own vocabulary was formed.)

Comment: That isn’t used in American English. You might want to add a mention of where that’s used.

Comment: @Davislor — Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited my answer to deal with your point.

Answer (score -4):

The first word that came to my mind was:

***renege***

wordnik via duckduckgo:

*intransitive verb* To fail to carry out a promise or commitment.

*intransitive verb* To fail to follow suit in cards when able and required by the rules to do so.

*intransitive verb* To renounce; disown.

For example searching "renege on our friendship" finds:

> Qassim was my friend until a few days ago. What made him renege on our
>   friendship? Where am I going to find another fridge on such a cold
>   night? What have I done to deserve all this?

from https://www.shortstoryproject.com/story/rabbits-of-baghdad/

Comment: I'm not sure that to renounce or disown is the intention in the example sentences.